# Can e-learning self assesment tools be incorporated in engineering education?

Tags: online-learning, distance-learning

Grading homeworks and continuous inventing of new homework problems is time consuming work. Based on positive homework we run pretest elimination. Eg. students who solve homework can attend semestral examination. Those tools are not enough to make students realize what level of knowledge they posses and the ratio of students writing exams in eg. mechanics classes is very high comparing to total number of those who pass tests.
Can e-learning systems be used to guide engineering students through learning process and which methods have been shown succesful, besides homework assignments? Do selfassesment tests help?

Comment: Why have you lmited this to engineering? The use of e-learning and these issues are most likely across the board - it may be other’s experience in different fields is relevant...

Comment: Because engineering classes have some specific problems eg. many answers are in form of the sketch, great number of social or other studies deal with written answers, very little sketches.

Comment: By sketch are you including first angle projection, third angle projection , isometric as well, do you think artists sketch? Do other classes require diagrams such as biology for example ...

Comment: Free body sketches, hand calculations etc.